# Rails password_confirmation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need help getting my user signup form to validate that password and password_confirmation match exactly.

Currently the form will pass the data entered into the password digest field in the database and will accept any input in the password_confirmation field, and will not give any errors.

My code is as follows;

**Model - user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    #attr_accessible :user_name, :email
    validates_confirmation_of :password
    has_secure_password

    validates :user_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 25 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
    validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

    has_many :trips
    has_many :countries, through: :trips

end
```

**view - new.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center" style="margin-top: 10px;" >Sign up</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 ">
      <%=form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :user_name, "Username" %>
        <%= f.text_field :user_name, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password Confirmation" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Create an account", class: 'form-control btn btn-primary' %>
      </div>
      <% end %> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also have bcrypt -v 3.1.7 in my gemfile. If any other info is needed let me know and I am happy to provide.

Comment: Do you have a password_digest column in your table?

Comment: how is your controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you are not getting the password_confirmation, to do that you should add

```
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
```

Also, in your controller, you should whitelist `:password_confirmation` into your permit section.

Validates confirmation only validates if password_confirmation is not nil.

Comment: Thanks I think the issue was in the controller with the abcense of :password_confirmation in my permits.

Oddly enough I had the validates statement in for :password_confirmation originally but it was giving me an error in the form so I took it out. However, I made both changes and now it is working.